# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Can't insert page ..... Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, exception, jsp, struts, weblogic

I just deployed an application to weblogic 10, and when I run my page, I get the custom error page with the following errror in the log.

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Can't insert page '/pages/header.jsp' : Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:899)
 at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
at jsp_servlet._pages._common.__onecolumntemplate._jsp__tag14(__onecolumntemplate.java:761)
 at jsp_servlet._pages._common.__onecolumntemplate._jspService(__onecolumntemplate.java:447)
 at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
```

Any idea what can cause that problem??

Comment: Does "/pages/header.jsp" exist and is it directly accessible via the browser? Is it making a remote call to another server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. The exception was coming from another stack above that.

Comment: Consider including the actual exception and trace in the custom error page :)

Comment: Would U please share with us your problem? I'm encountering such an issue, but do not know how to locate it yet.